# Incorrect output while executing program for multiple inputs

Tags: c++, c++11, output, cout

I've written a piece a code in C++ which tries to change some characters in String 1 and if matches with String 2 with in the specified number of changes, will print YES else NO. 
Here is the program:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
class DaisyTransformation
{
    private:
    int moves,status,length;
    char S1[50],S2[50],S3[50];
    public:
    void getValues( )
    {
        std::cin >> S1 >> S2 >> moves;
        length=strlen(S1);
    }
    void printValues( )
    {
        //std::cout <<"After"<< S1<<S2;
        if(status==0)
            std::cout << "No\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Yes\n";
    }
    void printValues1( )
    {
        std::cout <<"After"<< S1<<S2;

    }
    void calcPossibilities()
    {
        int i=1,j=0;
        //std::cout << "Before swapping" << S1<<S2;
        for(i=0;i<=moves&&j<length;){
            if(S1[j]==S2[j]){
                //S3[j]=S1[j];
                j++;
                //std::cout <<"\ncond"<< 1<<j;
            }
            else{
                if(S1[j]=='M'){
                    S1[j]='D';
                    i++;
                    j++;
                    //std::cout <<"\ncond1"<<i<<j ;
                }
                else{
                    S1[j]='M';
                    i++;
                    j++;
                    //std::cout << "\ncond2"<<i<<j;
                }
            }
        }
        if(strcmp(S1,S2)==0 && i==moves)
            status=1;
        else
            status=0;

    }

};
int main()
{
    DaisyTransformation dt[250];
    int noOfTestCases,i;
    std::cin>>noOfTestCases;
    for(i=0;i<noOfTestCases;i++){
        std::cin.clear();
        dt[i].getValues();
    }
    for(i=0;i<noOfTestCases;i++){
        /*if(i==24)
            dt[i].printValues1();*/
        dt[i].calcPossibilities();
        /*if(i==24)
            dt[i].printValues1();*/
        dt[i].printValues();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code runs perfect when my test cases are less(say 20 times). But, when I execute the same program for more test cases(say 30 and above), the program returns incorrect output.

Sample Input - executes fine

```
    4
MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
```

Output :

```
Yes
Yes
Yes
```

Sample Input - executes incorrectly

```
        30
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
    MMMMMDMDMDMMDMDMDM DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 12
```

Output

```
    Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
**No**
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
```

I still cannot find the reason why during the execution of 24th test case returns **NO** when it is supposed to return **YES**

**The compiler which is being used is g++ 4.8.4**

Comment: [That's weird, it works here](https://ideone.com/ERJs6d). Anything else you could add to reproduce?

Comment: This is my solution for a problem in a contest and when I submit my code it shows, wrong input for some test cases. When I give multiple test cases and run in their site, I run into this issue.

Comment: Maybe it's because of something else? I don't know, sorry

Comment: Can you provide the link to the original problem? Is it a live contest? What are the limits?

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/teamindus-hiring-challenge/problems/75f1089576554d05a6b40caa1a78e521/
<br>Time Limit: 1.0 sec(s) for each input file.
Memory Limit: 256 MB
Source Limit: 1024 KB
Marking Scheme: Marks are awarded if any testcase passes.
Allowed languages: C, CPP